# how to pass a parameter form a servlet to a java class

Tags: java, servlets

I want to pass a parameter from a servlet to a java class to I can use it they. how can i achieve this. thanks

tried this in my servlet

```
request.setAttribute(paramName, out);
```

and this on my java class

```
GetAnswerServlet an = new GetAnswerServlet(getAttribute(out));
```

but it didnt work

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting value by using `getAttribute(paramName)` instead of `out`?

Comment: I suggest using an action framework (like Stripes or the Spring framework), and not using the Servlet API directly.